# Python - pip pywin32 fails

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, python-3.7

Im trying to install pywin32 currently in a venv, but it seems to be failing - at least, pywin32 is not located in site-packages afterwards.
After entering `pip install pywin32`, i do not get an error - instead, it says `Downloading` and the URL, and afterwards i return to the shell - no error, no affirmation that the installation succeeds.

HOWEVER... the shell turns red.

[image]

Ive never seen such behavior, and the red color doesnt go away without having to restart the shell.

Why does the installation fail AND the shell turns red?

Comment: Maybe try a new virtualenv or another python version?

Comment: the venv was just freshly set up - doubt thats related, but ill try another python version

Comment: Switching to 3.6 made it work. odd

Comment: *Python3.7*  has just been released and it's normal that it's not very stable (nor are the modules built for it). Try `pip install -v pywin32` for more verbose output.

Answer (score 1):

The color turns red because it is dying in the middle of running. Entering the command `Color 07` will fix this.

Do you have admin access? Is your virtualenv activated?

Comment: Ran CMD with admin and have venv active, yes

Comment: Can you try executing `pip install pypiwin32` for me?

Comment: I tried that before - it didnt throw an error but didnt show up in pip list either

Comment: Try manually entering the path like `pip install pypiwin32 --target="C:/Something"`

Comment: Ah, when i set the target to be Lib/Site-Packages in the venv it turns red again, and when installing it on desktop nothing shows up there aswell

Answer (score 1):

To complete this question ;-)

Try to create a new virtualenv with python 3.6:

```
$ mkvirtualenv testPyWin32 --python=python3.6
$ pip install pywin32
```

Comment: "pip show pywin32" command returns non zero exit status 1. I want to also see info about package. Any idea?